# Reading the definition of intersection of a family of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Suppose $F$ is a family of sets. Then the intersection of $F$ is the set $\cap F$ defined as follows:

$$ \cap F = \{x \mid \forall A. A \in F \rightarrow x \in A)\}$$

I am having trouble understanding this. This is how I am currently reading it:

The intersection of $F$ (which is a family of sets), is the set $x$ such that, For all sets $A$, if $A$ is an element of $F$ then the set $x$ is an element of $A$.

According to this reading, $A$ and $x$ are both sets, how can $x$ which is a set be an element of $A$. Surely there is something wrong with my reading. But I cannot figure out what.

Comment: The *intersection* of two sets $A$ and $B$ is the set of "common" elements, i.e. the set of all and only those elements that belongs to both $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Thus, for a "family" $F$, its *intersection* is the set of those elements that belongs to all the members of the family $F$.

Comment: It's not "the set $x$ such that ..." but "the set *that consists of all* $x$ such that ..."

Comment: This has nothing to do (in principle) with the "nature" of $x$: $x$ must be an *element* of $A$, for any $A$. In most "formal set theories, every "object" is a set, and thus $x$ is also a set. But what matter here is the relationship $\in$ between a set $A$, a family (i.e. a set) of sets $F$ and an element $x$ whatever.

Comment: Thus, the def reads: an "object" whatever $x$ belongs to $\bigcap F$ **iff** it belongs to every member of $F$. In formula, $x \in \bigcap F \Leftrightarrow \forall A \ (A \in F \to x \in A)$.

Comment: The part "$x$ belongs to every member of $F$" reads: "if $A$ is a member of $F$, then $x$ belongs to $A$".

Comment: besides reading the definition wrong, I had not given enough thought to what an intersection in a family of sets would mean. Thanks for the insight Mauro

Comment: Terminologically, I would call $F$ simply a set of sets. For me, a "family" means a collection of sets indexed by another set which could be represented by a function (in two equivalent but quite different ways). Of course, if we have an $I$-indexed family of sets $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$, we have a set of sets $\{A_i\mid i\in I\}$. For the purpose of intersections this distinction isn't very important: $\bigcap\{A_i\mid i\in I\} = \bigcap_{i\in I}A_i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation

$$\{ x \mid \forall A. (A \in F \rightarrow x \in A)\}$$

is an example of the commonly used notion of *set abstraction*; we build the set of elements that satisfy a given condition. $x$ is a bound variable here that ranges over *elements*.

The intersection of $F$ is the set $Z$ such that $x$ belongs to $Z$ if for every set $A$ in the family $F$, $x$ is an element of $A$.

Comment: so A here is ranging over all the sets in F?

Comment: Yes. This is clear from the condition in the set abstraction.

Answer (score 1):

The intersection of the family $F$ contains all of the elements $x$ such that if $A$ is a member of the family $F$, then $x$ is contained in $A$.  That is, if $x\in F$, then $x\in A$ for all $A \in F$.  Each $A$ and $\cap F$ are sets, anything labeled $x$ is (potentially) an element of one or more of these sets.